# Java Overloading Overriding query

Tags: java

1)Why can't the following neither overload nor override each other:

```
void meth(List<Integer> a){}
 void meth(List<String> a){}
```

If the above parameters result in same type erasure, why can't they be overridden.
If they can't be overridden that means the parameters are somehow different thus shall be overloaded if in same class but its not so.Isn't the above a conflict then??

2)Why is the following behavior shown in overriding?

```
a)void test(int a){}  //parent class method  
public/protected void test(int a){}  //child class method  (Overridden)



 b)void test(int a){}  //parent class method  
private void test(int a){}  //child class method (not overridden)  


c)public test(int a){}  //parent class method  
 protected void test(int a){}  //child class method (not overridden)
```

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such, and tell us what you have come up with so far.

Answer (score 3):

1- IN java - generics are implemented by erasures. This means that the actual signatures of both the versions evaluate to

`void meth(List a){}`

Obviously you cannot have two methods with the exact signature in the same class definition.

2
. Your examples will all result in compile time errors except the first one if you specify `public`.

Comment: The above evaluates to void meth(List<Object> a){} or just void meth(List a){} coz at runtime no generics prevails.Please clarify

Comment: @user1649415 , it is indeed converted to `List` and not `List<Object>`. My point was that basically all type parameters are replaced by their erasures - and this leads to the fact that they two methods end up with same signature - which is the reason why they cannot be called as overloads.

Answer (score 1):

1). They cannot be overloaded because with the empty list or list of nulls will be impossible to define, which method to call. They cannot be overriden because they have different signature and that is restricted.

2). Because the child method has less visibility then parent one and by language spec - they can't.

Comment: You have stated that in (1) they hav different signatures hence not overridden but dont they evaluate down to void meth(List<Object> a){} which is same signature for both